# Questions about rings and ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, extension-field

Given a ring $R$ and an ideal $I \triangleleft R$ i'm trying to make some conclusions about the quotient
$I/R$.

Let for instance $R=\mathbb Q[x]$ and $I=(x^4-16)$. I'm looking for a zero divisor unequal to 0 to show that the quotient $R/I$ is not a field. Is it true to say $x=\pm 2$ since $(\pm 2)^4$=16?

Now let $R = (\mathbb Z / 8 \mathbb Z)[x]$ and $I=(x^3+x+1)$. Again I would like to find a zero divisor to show that $R/I$ is not a field, but I would also like to show that $x \in R/I$ is a unit. Could someone model this answer for me? That would be very kind. I have incredible difficulty working on any $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ and I am not sure how to do either of this.

Finally, I thought of letting $R = \mathbb Z[x]$ and $I=(x^2+2)$. In this case, I would like to find an element that does not have an inverse, and show that the quotient $R/I$ is a identity ring. Here, I was considering two somewhat related cases. First of all, say I had $(x^2+2)$, then that would be $\mathbb Z[i]$. If it were $(x^2-2)$ then it would just be $\{ a+b \sqrt 2 : a,b\in\mathbb Z\}.$ Can I use either of these to conclude anything about $R/I$?

Comment: You are of course right, I expressed myself incorrectly. They are seperate, ie, I would like to find a unit, and also a zero divisor. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: For the first example you can see that $(x^2-4)(x^2+4)=x^4-16$ and thus $x^2-4+I$ and $x^2+4+I$ are zero divisors in the quotient $R/I$

Comment: @PeterMelech What does $+I$ mean in this case?

Comment: This is a standard notation for the residue class, e.g. $x^2-4+I=\{x^2-4+f:f\in I\}$, for the second example: $R/I$ can't be a field since $\mathbb{Z}/(8)$ is not a field, note that $4\cdot 2=0$ in $ \mathbb{Z}/(8)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First example. You should find a polynomial, but not substitute any number in $x$. $x^4 - 16 = (x^2 - 4)(x^2 + 4)$ so $x^2-4$ and $x^2+4$ are zero divisors.

Second one. $x(-x^2-1) = -x^3-x = 1$ so $x$ is a unit. To find a zero divisor, try to find a factorisation of $x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_8$. This is a key to your problem as it follows from the previous example.

The third one. Yes, $R/I = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}i]$. So the analogy with $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can help.

Comment: +1 In the second example zero divisors are easy to find since the ring of coefficients contains them: $4\cdot 2=0$

Comment: Yes, for the second one still $4 \cdot 2 = 8 = 0$ is OK :) But it's a good exercise)

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Now I am curious about the final question. In the last example, I take it that showing that $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt 2]$ is a euclidean domain proves it is an integral domain. However, despite my anology, I am unsure as to where the element without an inverse in $Z[i \sqrt 2]$ comes from. Can I merely argue that since 2 is indeed an element in R/I, but since 1/2 is not an element, it is not a field?

Comment: @WundSprayPredator yes, the logic regarding non-invertible elements is the same as in the trivial case of $\mathbb{Z}$. By the way, when you obtain a euclidean norm, you'll find a lot more examples of non-invertible elements.

Comment: Marvelous. I thank you for your time.